# What guarantees the thread safety of Guava's ImmutableList?

Tags: java, multithreading, guava, java-memory-model

The Javadoc in Guava's [ImmutableList](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java) says that the class has the properties of Guava's [ImmutableCollection](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableCollection.java), one of which is thread safety:

> **Thread safety.** It is safe to access this collection concurrently from multiple threads.

But look at how the `ImmutableList` is built by its Builder - The `Builder` keeps all elements in a `Object[]` (that's okay since no one said that the builder was thread safe) and upon construction passes that array (or possibly a copy) to the constructor of [RegularImmutableList](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/RegularImmutableList.java):

```
public abstract class ImmutableList<E> extends ImmutableCollection<E>
implements List<E>, RandomAccess {
    ...
    static <E> ImmutableList<E> asImmutableList(Object[] elements, int length) {
      switch (length) {
        case 0:
          return of();
        case 1:
          return of((E) elements[0]);
        default:
          if (length < elements.length) {
            elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, length);
          }
          return new RegularImmutableList<E>(elements);
      }
    }
    ...
    public static final class Builder<E> extends ImmutableCollection.Builder<E> {
        Object[] contents;
        ...
        public ImmutableList<E> build() { //Builder's build() method
          forceCopy = true;
          return asImmutableList(contents, size);
        }
        ...
    }

}
```

What does `RegularImmutableList` do with these elements? What you'd expect, simply initiates its internal array, which is then used for all read oprations:

```
class RegularImmutableList<E> extends ImmutableList<E> {
    final transient Object[] array;

    RegularImmutableList(Object[] array) {
      this.array = array;
    }

    ...
}
```

How is this be thread safe? What guarantees the **happens-before** relationship between the **writes** performed in the `Builder` and the **reads** from `RegularImmutableList`?

According to the [Java memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) there is a happens-before relationship in only five cases (from the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) for `java.util.concurrent`):

> - Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order.
> - An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method
>     entry) of that same monitor. And because the happens-before relation
>     is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking
>     happen-before all actions subsequent to any thread locking that
>     monitor.
> - A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that same field. Writes and reads of volatile fields have similar
>     memory consistency effects as entering and exiting monitors, but do
>     not entail mutual exclusion locking.
> - A call to start on a thread happens-before any action in the started thread.
> - All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a join on that thread.

None of these seem to apply here. If some thread builds the list and passes its reference to some other threads without using locks (for example via a `final` or `volatile` field), I don't see what guarantees thread-safety. What am I missing?

**Edit:**

Yes, the write of the reference to the array is thread-safe on account of it being `final`. So that's clearly thread safe.
What I was wondering about were the writes of the individual elements. The elements of the array are neither `final` nor `volatile`. Yet they seem to be written by one thread and read by another without synchronization.

So the question can be boiled down to "if thread A writes to a `final` field, does that guarantee that other threads will see not just that write but all of A's previous writes as well?"

Comment: Your proposed race condition isn't clear. Did you also read [17.5, final field semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5)? Note specifically that `RegularImmutableList.array` *is* final.

Comment: The writes performed in the builder happen-before the creation of the list, since both happen in the same thread (see first case in your list). Can you elaborate and post an example where a write in the builder wouldn't happen before a read, and specify what those writes and reads would be?

Comment: @chrylis 
Yes, the write of the reference to the array is thread-safe on account of it being `final`. So that's clearly thread safe.
What I was wondering about were the writes of the individual elements. The elements of the array are neither `final` nor `volatile`. Yet they seem to be written by one thread and read by another without synchronization.

Comment: @JBNizet I've edited the question. I'm asking about the writes of the individual elements, not the array itself.

Comment: The writes into the array happen on the same thread (i.e., happen-before) the assignment of that array to the field.

Comment: @chrylis Writes can be reordered by the compiler. Are there guarantees regarding the order of writes to final and non-final fields?

Comment: @Matt (emphasis mine): "The usage model for final fields is a simple one: Set the final fields for an object in that object's constructor; and do not write a reference to the object being constructed in a place where another thread can see it before the object's constructor is finished. If this is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final fields. **It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are**."

Comment: Yes, there are guarantees--that's specifically what the "program order" hb means.

Comment: @JBNizet Does that mean that writes to `final` fields are essentially memory barriers that cause the cpu to flush the cache to the main memory? The writes into that array could have been in the cpu cache.

Comment: I don't know enough about that to tell. I'm just relying on what the specification says.

Comment: @JBNizet Could you post an answer? That quote from the memory model seems to be the best answer so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMM guarantees safe initialization (all values initialized in the constructor will be visible to readers) if all fields in the object are `final` and there is no leakage of `this` from constructor<sup>1</sup>:

```
class RegularImmutableList<E> extends ImmutableList<E> {

    final transient Object[] array;
      ^

    RegularImmutableList(Object[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }
}
```

[The final field semantics](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/ae45df3285c9/src/share/vm/opto/parse1.cpp#l930) guarantees that readers will see an up-to-date array:

> The effects of all initializations must be committed to memory before
> any code after constructor publishes the reference to the newly
> constructed object.

---

<sup>Thank you to @JBNizet and to @chrylis for the link to the JLS.</sup>

<sup>1 - "If this is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final fields. **It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are**." - JLS [§17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5).</sup>

Comment: Yes, the write of the reference to the array is thread-safe on account of it being `final`. So that's clearly thread safe.
What I was wondering about were the writes of the individual elements. The elements of the array are neither `final` nor `volatile`. Yet they seem to be written by one thread and read by another without synchronization.

Comment: That's a very good find. Thank you. But it only applies to OpenJDK, not Java in general. The fact that it's something that OpenJDK guarantees doesn't mean anything regarding other implementations if it's not in the memory model.

Comment: Wait, that seems to apply to "the effects of initialization", meaning the write of the reference to `array`. Not the writes into the array itself.

Comment: @Malt Any object shared by threads must be created and then somehow given to other threads. That process has to ensure that every bit of the object creation is visible to every thread that receives the created object. This is true for all objects and there is nothing special about this one. However you create the object and then tell other threads about it must establish the necessary happens-before relationship between construction and subsequent access.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't understand your point. I never said that there's something special about this list. It's obvious that when passing objects between threads we must preserve the happens-before relationship, that's the premise of the question.

Comment: @Malt Then you probably should have just asked what ensures thread safety when an object is created in one thread and then passed to another thread. The answer is in your question, "*Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order.*". So if a thread creates an object and then (in its program order) does something after that to make that object visible to other threads, that establishes the required relationship between the construction (and all its effects) and the giving other threads access.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated: "*Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order.*"

Obviously, if a thread could somehow access the object before the constructor was even invoked, you would be screwed. So something must prevent the object from being accessed before its constructor returns. But once the constructor returns, anything that lets another thread access the object is safe because it happens after in the constructing thread's program order.

Basic thread safety with any shared object is accomplished by ensuring that whatever allows threads to access the object does not take place until the constructor returns, establishing that anything the constructor might do happens before any other thread might access the object.

The flow is:

1. The object does not exist and cannot be accessed.
2. Some thread calls the object's constructor (or does whatever else is needed to get the object ready to be used).
3. That thread then does something to allow other threads to access the object.
4. Other threads can now access the object.

Program order of the thread invoking the constructor ensures that no part of 4 happens until all of 2 is done.

Note that this applies just the same if things need to be done after the constructor returns, you can just consider them logically part of the construction process. And similarly, parts of the job can be done by other threads so long as anything that needs to see work done by another thread cannot start until some relationship is established with the work that other thread did.

Does that not 100% answer your question?

To restate:

> How is this be thread safe? What guarantees the happens-before relationship between the writes performed in the Builder and the reads from RegularImmutableList?

The answer is whatever prevented the object from being accessed before the constructor was even called (which has to be something, otherwise we'd be completely screwed) continues to prevent the object from being accessed until after the constructor returns. The constructor is effectively an atomic operation because no other thread could possibly attempt to access the object while it's running. Once the constructor returns, whatever the thread that called the constructor does to allow other threads to access the object necessarily takes place after the constructor returns because, "[e]ach action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order."

And, one more time:

> If some thread builds the list and passes its reference to some other threads without using locks (for example via a final or volatile field), I don't see what guarantees thread-safety. What am I missing?

The thread first builds the list and then next passes its reference. The building of the list "happens-before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order" and thus happens-before the passing of the reference. Thus any thread that sees the passing of the reference happens-after the building of the list completed.

Were this not the case, there would be no good way to construct an object in one thread and then give other threads access to it. But this is perfectly safe to do because whatever method you use to hand the object from one thread to another will establish the necessarily relationship.

Comment: According to the memory model, the thread that built the object is guaranteed to see the effect of all of its writes. But writes can be reordered (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4). Plus, some writes might have already reached the main memory, while others could have remained in the thread's cache. So the java memory model is very careful about guarantees around which writes of the original thread are going to be visible to other threads.

Comment: So my question can be boiled down to "does a write to a final field by thread A guarantee that other threads see the all previous writes by the same thread"? To which the closest answer is the quote JB Nizet found: "Set the final fields for an object in that object's constructor... If this is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final fields. It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are. "

Comment: @Malt It doesn't matter either way in this case though. The other threads can't possibly even attempt the read until they are given access to the object somehow (otherwise they could access it before it's even constructed). And whatever gives them access happens after the writes.

Comment: Would you have said the same if the array wasn't `final`? No, right? That would clearly be unsafe. It has nothing to do with how the constructed list is passed to other threads. The list might be passed from thread to thread without locks or volatile writes. What guarantees the thread safety regardless of how the list is used is that the array is final. `final` guarantees that the writes of the array elements have been flushed to main memory before the construction is complete. That's what JB Nizet quoted from the memory model.

Comment: Yes, I would say the same if the array wasn't `final`. What guarantees the thread safety is that the list *can't* be passed from thread to thread by any method whatsoever until the constructor returns and the thread that called the constructor does something, *anything*, to make that object accessible to other threads. If the object couldn't be accessed before the constructor started, it can't be accessed until after the constructor returns in the program order of the thread that calls the constructor, and that's sufficient.

Comment: I think you're mistaken. If the array wasn't final, the thread that built the list would be guaranteed to see a fully constructed object. But there is not such guarantee regarding other threads since the writes could have been reordered by the compiler (see example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) or written to cache and not the main memory. It's explicitly demonstrated by this example in the Java memory model: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5

Comment: Would you like to continue discussing this in chat? This is getting a bit long for the comments.

Comment: @Malt How would the thread give other threads access to the object without establishing the required relationship? And if a thread did that, wouldn't that be a bug in that thread regardless of how this class is implemented? Consider an immutable integer. It would be a bug to construct an instance of the immutable integer and then somehow give another thread access to that immutable integer if you didn't ensure the thread could see the results of the constructor. It has nothing to do with the thread-safety of the integer but of the code that passes the reference.

Comment: As demonstrated by example 17.5-1 linked above, a thread could write the list to to a non-volatile/non-final field. Then, Java doesn't guarantee that the other thread would see the writes performed by the first thread in the same order. This is explicitly written in both example 17.5-1 and 17.4-1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183320/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-malt).

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about two different things in here.

1. Access to already built `RegularImmutableList` and its `array` is thread safe because there wont be any concurrent writes and reads to that array. Only concurrent reads.
2. The threading issue can happen when you pass it to another thread. But that has nothing to do with `RegularImmutableList` but with how other threads see reference to it. 
   Lets say one thread creates `RegularImmutableList` and passes its reference to another thread. For the other thread to see that the reference has been updated and is now pointing to new created `RegularImmutableList` you will need to use either `synchronization` or `volatile`.

EDIT:

I think the concern OP has is how JMM makes sure that whatever got written into the `array` after its creation from one building thread gets visible to other threads after its reference gets passed to them.

This happens by the use or `volatile` or `synchronization`. When for example reader thread assigns `RegularImmutableList` to volatile variable the JMM will make sure that all writes to array get flashed into main memory and when other thread reads from it JMM makes sure that it will see all flashed writes.

Comment: 1. The writes to that array were performed in a different thread. What guarantees that they will be visible to the readers? 

2. I don't understand your second point. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Malt. I hope my update to the answer explains it better.

Comment: @Malt. Not sure where is my "misunderstanding". Write to `volatile` should flash cache into the main and read from `volatile` should invalidate the cache so that other thread will read from main.